# 'Character_Creation' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python

I keep getting this error 'Character_Creation' object has no attribute 'choice' but i clearly defined choice as, choice = input(">") and made the object character creation. Any help on how to fix this?

```
class Character_Creation():

def __init__(self):

    print("""Character Creation

Whats your name?""")

    Name = input(">")
    print("""Chose your career
          Type b for Blacksmith, a weapon-smith
          Type bo for BodyBuilder, a Russian strong man
          Type m for Merchant , a man with strong trade skills
          """)
    choice = input(">")

class Classes():
def Blacksmith():
    health = 100
    attack = 30
    defence = 10
    money = 100
def Bodybuilder():
    health = 150
    attack = 10
    defense = 30
    money = 100
def Merchant():
    health = 100
    attack = 5
    defence = 5
    money = 500

class Stats():
def __init__(self):
    if c.choice == "m":
        cl.Merchant()
        print(attack)











t=Title_Screen()
c=Character_Creation()
cl=Classes()
s=Stats()
```

Comment: No, you didn't. Try `self.choice = input(">")`

Answer (score 0):

JBernardo is correct that you aren't using `self` correctly. More broadly, though, your use of classes is a bit odd. `CharacterCreation` seems better suited to a class method than a whole class, and having a class `Classes` with instance methods that define then discard local variables is a bit odd. I think want you are trying to do looks more like:

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, defence, money):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.money = money

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name):
        characters = {"bodybuilder": (150, 10, 30, 100), ...}
        return cls(name, *characters[name])

...    

if choice.lower() == "bo":
    character = Character.create("bodybuilder")
```

If you need the different types of `Character` to have different instance methods and attributes, use inheritance:

```
def Blacksmith(Character):

    def hammer_metal(self):
```